# Is it possible to use shogun in android ndk?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, shogun

I want to use shogun C++ in Android NDK. Thus I am wondering:

1. what is the C++ library dependencies for shogun?

   a quick look at the shogun github repo, it seems that there are quick many dependecies as there is many Findxxx.cmake inside the project.

   Also, shogun does provide interface to other languages, e.g. python, ruby, C#. I don't care about the interfaces, is it easy to disable them?
2. Is it easy possible to compile shogun as a shared library for android?

   The Android now support build with ndk-build and CMake.

   - It is possible to build shogun with nkd-build?
   - If I need to build with CMake, do I need to adapt a lot of CMake scripts?
   - Is there any example project which demonstrate the use of shogun in Android?

Answer (score 1):

there's absolutely no reason why shogun could not be used on an android phone. Shogun has official packages on Fedora and as part of the Fedora build system shogun is successfully compiled and distributed on many different ARM architectures.

By default---if you dont specify explicitly---shogun is only build as a c++ library, i.e. none of the interfaces you've mentioned are compiled by default.

But we (shogun developers) don't know anybody who has done this before, but again this only means that it requires a little bit of cmake & android ndk hacking. I've just done some googling and seems these scripts could be helpful to achieve your goals: https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake